# What should the hamming weights be between every iteration of AES?

Tags: encryption, aes

I have an assignment where I have to print out the hamming weights between every iteration of AES's diffusion steps and I have been getting a maximum weight on every iteration, but I can't seem to verify if that is correct or not.

It seems like the assignment was given to show that the weights increase as diffusion goes on, so I am a little suspicious of the constant weights of 1?

Should they be 1 on every iteration?

Comment: How do you calculate? Not clear from here. Your mistake could be anywhere.